# Change contrast/gamma in external monitor

Tags: xorg

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 64bit on a computer that has only Intel HD graphics (i.e. no dedicated graphic card like NVidia).

I recently dug up my old CRT (a 15" HCL), and it looks a bit dull when connected to my laptop (the laptop screen looks fine). I was able to get around this on **Windows** by using the Color Enhancement sliders in Intel Graphics Properties.

I tried using https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/‎ , but the screen looks dull even with the setting at full

Is there any way to do this (i.e. change contrast/gamma for external monitor only) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the Gamma of the xserver using xrandr. First you must know the name of the output to the device/monitor:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 228mm
   1024x768       60.0*+   75.1     70.1  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you can see the name of my outputs are in bold. Once you know the name, you can change the gamma:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --gamma 5:3:4
```

Let me explain the `1:1:1`: `--gamma <red>:<green>:<blue>`. If you already had knowledge about the values you can play with them, if you didn't liked the results (or just tossed the monitor) just do:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --gamma 1
```

This will reset all gamma to `1`.

Comment: Thanks, xrandr helps somewhat. I'd like to change contrast as well, is there some way to make that happen (I am not able to use xcalib properly)

Comment: @3l4ng if I'm not mistaken, contrast is hardware managed (ie the monitor, tv) and Intel Graphics Controler just accessed the monitor preferences and changed it there. I don't know if linux is able to do this, and I would play better with the builtin monitor controllers or changing the data cable.

Comment: It's `--gamma 1:1:1` (at least, with xrandr 1.4.1, `--gamma 1` won't work)

Comment: Gamma is not the same as contrast.